# Google Maps query businesses Near Me Search

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

### Objective

Client wants a map on the search results page that shows a Google Map with all business listings, matching the users search parameters, that are near that user.

### Background

I have a client who is building a business directory website.

This client is currently using a WordPress plugin called GeoDirectory and would like to have a map on the search results page that shows a Google Map with all business listings, matching the users search parameters, that are near that user.

These would not be the businesses on the website they would be the businesses that you would get if you did a search on Google say "restaurants near me" and it would show those businesses.

The client wants it to look exactly like the google map that results from that search so it would take the query created by the GeoDirectory plugin and show a list of businesses from the clients site that match a specific category and also a google map of other businesses in the area that are listed on Google.

### Question

Is this possible?

I don't really have a link to show an example but if you type in "restaurants near me" in the google search bar and click on the map that pops up in the search results you will see what I mean.

Comment: With any solution you are tried ??

Comment: I edited your post to make it concise and transparent. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before making a question next time.

Comment: Thank you Flame_Phoenix I was in a hurry this morning.

Answer (score 1):

### Is it possible?

I don't know WordPress, but coming from a Google Maps background, I can definitely tell you that **yes, it is possible**.

### What can I use?

Depending where you make your request from, you can either use the [Places API Web Service (server side)](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) or the [JavaScript API with the Places Library (for client side)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

For more information about the Places API and related products you can visit https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

### How can the Places API help me?

The Places API Web Service and its library for the JavaScript API have a functionality that you can use called [PlacesSearch](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search), which is exactly what you need.

### Examples and Docs

To use this functionality, lets say, using the Web API, you need to make a GET request like the following:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters
```

Using the JavaScript API, you would send a request like this:

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests
```

With this information, you can include a map, and quickly get the information you need by having the user type in a text box.

The example below demonstrates how this concept works

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search

Comment: The example is not exactly what the client wants. I needs to have the scroll on the left side with the business names, images, links etc...like when you actually search on Google. I've tried going through the API files and was not successful finding exactly what the client wants. Since the plugin he is using already pulls the api key and everything thing in the API documentation required you put the API key in the string. I'm sure I'm missing something since I am not that familiar with the Google Maps API.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Google Maps is a webapp that uses Google Maps APIs and Services. It is designed as an example of what you can do when you use Google Maps APIs and Services. You can use our services to build something like the Google Maps webapp, but you have to do it yourself. As for the API key, yes, you either need an API key or a client-id depending if the client purchased the Premium plan or if he is using the standard plan.